# SMS Template creation in Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am using Twilio node.js API in microsoft azure for sending SMS. I want to create some predefined template like 'Dear customer your account balance is Rs 55555'.

Is it possible to create SMS Template in Twilio account ? Is Twilio supports Transaction SMS ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked out the [Twilio tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/)? This one on [SMS notifications in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/node/express) might help.

Comment: sending SMS to phone is working fine for me. But I want use dynamic content body instead of static body. For example 'Dear customer your account balance is Rs XXXXX' will be the template and this may be defined in Twilio account. Then i want to use this template in my node.js code and will replace XXXXX with dynamic content. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your dynamic content in a manner similar to the following example where you respond to a sender by name (shown in Python) from the Quickstarts:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/replying-to-sms-messages

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml

app = Flask(__name__)

# Try adding your own number to this list!
callers = {
    "+14158675309": "Curious George",
    "+14158675310": "Boots",
    "+14158675311": "Virgil",
}

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_monkey():
    """Respond and greet the caller by name."""

    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    if from_number in callers:
        message = callers[from_number] + ", thanks for the message!"
    else:
        message = "Thanks for the message!"

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.message(message)

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```